# How to write the VTKUnstructuredGrid into binary string with vtkUnstructuredGridWriter?

Tags: python

With python2.7, I used `vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridWriter()` to write unstructured_grid as binary string, and then used `vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()` to read this binary string again to a unstructured_grid. But I couldn't get the same grid as the original one.

Here is my code:

Writer

```
writer = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridWriter()
writer.SetInputData(grid_original)
writer.WriteToOutputStringOn()
writer.Write()  
binary_string = writer.GetBinaryOutputString()
```

Reader

```
reader = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.ReadFromInputStringOn()
reader.SetBinaryInputString(binary_string, len(binary_string))
reader.Update()
unstructured_grid = reader.GetOutput()
```

The cells number in the original unstructured grid are 29629. But after writing and reading the cells number in the new unstructured_grid is 0. Is

This writing and reading methods are successful when I use

*writer.GetOutputString()* instead of *writer.Get**Binary**OutputString()*,

*reader.SetInputString(non_binary_string)* instead of *reader.SetBinaryInputString(binary_string, len(binary_string))*